# Operand should contain 1 column(s) error

Tags: mysql, sql, operand, mysql-error-1241

I have an sql query that was returning some incorrect results due to product id's being duplicated for linked products, so i added the following to the end of my query expecting it to only take the first instance of any product id:

```
AND pc.products_id 
IN
(SELECT
pc.products_id, MIN(categories_id)
FROM
zen_products_to_categories pc
GROUP BY
pc.products_id)
```

But i get an Operand should contain 1 column(s) error when i run the process. I ran that query on it's own and it only gave me each product id once, so not sure why i get the error.

The full query i now have is:

```
SELECT p.products_quantity, p.abebooks_status, 
p.products_id AS id, 
p.products_status AS prodStatus, 
FORMAT( IFNULL(s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price),2) AS price, 
pc.categories_id AS prodCatID, 
c.parent_id AS catParentID, 
cd.categories_name AS catName 
FROM 
zen_products p 
JOIN zen_products_description pd ON p.products_id=pd.products_id 
JOIN zen_products_to_categories pc ON p.products_id=pc.products_id 
JOIN zen_categories c ON pc.categories_id=c.categories_id 
JOIN zen_categories_description cd ON c.categories_id=cd.categories_id 
left join zen_specials s on ( s.products_id = p.products_id AND ( (s.expires_date > CURRENT_DATE) OR (s.expires_date = 0) ) ) 
WHERE p.products_price > 0 and p.products_status = 1 
AND pc.products_id 
IN 
(SELECT pc.products_id, MIN(categories_id) 
FROM zen_products_to_categories pc GROUP BY pc.products_id) 
ORDER BY catName ASC
```

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work when i add the extra query because it's got me baffled

Comment: Are you serious!!! This question was asked in November 2013 and you come along in October 2014 and mark it as a duplicate. Glad i have better things to do with my time. Ridiculous!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with:

```
AND (pc.products_id, pc.categories_id) 
    IN
    (SELECT
       pc.products_id, MIN(categories_id)
     FROM
       zen_products_to_categories pc
     GROUP BY
       pc.products_id)
```

**Edit:**

In MySQL a subquery like this is usually slow. You should have better luck with a JOIN:

```
SELECT ....
FROM
  ....
  INNER JOIN (SELECT
                products_id, MIN(categories_id) min_categories_id
              FROM
                zen_products_to_categories
              GROUP BY
                products_id) min_ct
  ON pc.products_id=min_ct.products_id
     AND pc.categories_id=min_ct.min_categories_id
WHERE
  ....
```

Comment: That works in that the query doesn't throw an error. BUT, it takes well over 30 seconds to process something that took around 3 seconds previously. Is there a way to speed up the overall query. The database has around 12,000 active products, but i wouldnt have expected it to take that long

Answer (score 0):

Subquery should  return one column when you are matching against single column  remove `MIN(categories_id)` from your subquery

```
AND pc.products_id 
IN
(SELECT
pc.products_id
FROM
zen_products_to_categories pc
GROUP BY
pc.products_id)
```